# Windows 10 start menu search locations

Tags: windows-10, search, start-menu

I've recently taken the step up to Windows 10, but have a question I can't quite seem to find the answer to anywhere.

I have made a few custom shortcuts to folders, programs and files I'd like to appear when searched for using the start menu search.

For example if I have a folder called "Shortcuts" and in this folder I have a shortcut to "Vacation2016", how do I make Windows 10 show me my "Vacations2016" folder when I hit start and type "Vacati" (or the entire folder name)?

What folders does the Windows start menu search keep tabs on when looking for results to present, and how can I add my own folder, "Shortcuts", to this lookup?

Comment: You are looking for options related to the Windows 10 search index.  Here is a good tutorial that will help explain things in detail:  [How to Choose Which Files Windows Search Indexes on Your PC](https://www.howtogeek.com/272158/how-to-choose-which-files-windows-search-indexes-on-your-pc/)